# What is the meaning of this command?

Tags: linux, bash

What is the meaning of following command, especially this part `</dev/console`

```
exec >/dev/console 2>&1 </dev/console
```

Comment: Break the question into smaller pieces. Do you know bash IO redirection? If not learn it. Next, do you know what `/dev/console` is? I don't =p

Comment: i don't know the meaning of last part "</dev/console".

Comment: what is </dev/console used for in this whole command. i know exec >/dev/console 2>&1 to redirect the result to console standard output, but i am confused about the usage of "</dev/console", i think it is useless

Comment: so for this command, </dev/console gives its content to exec, right?

Answer (score 1):

`<f` sets the stdin for the given command:

```
echo abc >f; nl <f
```

is similar to (except for [FIFO vs file differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654025/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-command/20655114?noredirect=1#comment103804110_20655114)):

```
echo abc >f; cat f | nl
```

With `exec <f`, all stdin from that point onwards will come from file `f` as explained [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17891.html), and with `exec >f` all stdout from this point onwards will go to `f`.

About the `/dev/console`, doing:

```
sudo bash 'echo a > /dev/console'
```

outputs `a` to the current tty, independently of redirections. Therefore, to see this working you many need to be on a textual tty (Ctrl+Alt+F2 , F3, etc. on Ubuntu).

Using `/dev/tty` instead of `/dev/console` may or not be different according to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0). On Ubuntu, they are different, and using `/dev/tty` is better since it also works on xterm windows. On Ubuntu also `/dev/tty` does not require sudo to use, so I will use it on the following examples.

To see this at work, create a script:

```
echo '
echo a
echo b >/dev/tty
' > s
```

and do:

```
sudo bash s >/dev/null
```

You will see `b` on the tty, because `a` went to the stdout and then to `null`.

The same goes for `>/dev/null`, but for the stdin of the script.

Therefore finally putting everything together this means that even if we call the program as:

```
echo a | ./a.sh >/dev/null
```

from that point onwards stdout and stderr will go to the tty and stdin will come from the tty, which would not happen without that command (stdin would come from a pipe, and stdout would go to `/dev/null`).

For portability reasons, I do not recommend that you rely on device files, since I think they are not specified by POSIX.

Comment: you two example command cannot exec successfully in bash. Anyway, my question is answered in a way. Thanks.

Comment: @mailzyok You are right, examples it should work now.

Comment: I wouldn't describe those as equivalent commands. `cat f | nl` is making `nl`'s stdin a FIFO connected to the stdout of the `cat` program, whereas `nl <f` is making `nl`'s stdin a real (seekable) file descriptor. If you do that with something like `wc -c` on a multi-GB file, it'll be instant on the real-file-descriptor case, but very slow on the FIFO case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I didn't know that, so on the C level you can seek `stdin` if it is opened as `<f`?

Comment: That is correct.